# How do you start FreeCAD in Ubuntu 18.04 after installation?

Tags: 18.04

I just installed FreeCAD under Ubuntu 18.04 from Ubuntu Software. In Ubuntu Software, I can click the Launch button to launch FreeCAD. But when I try to start FreeCAD from a terminal or from the start menu, it's nowhere to be found.

Where is the main program to start FreeCAD located?

Answer (score 0):

You can start it via `/usr/bin/freecad`.  However, that's just a symlink to the *actual* binary: `/usr/lib/freecad/bin/FreeCAD`

Edit: the above assumed that you installed it as a .deb package.  You've installed a .snap package version which will have a different directory structure.  http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/snap-vs-deb-package has more information about snap package directory structure.

Comment: Both the `/usr/bin/freecad` and `/usr/lib/freecad/bin/FreeCAD` do not exist on my computer. I believe FreeCAD is located under `/snap/freecad` on my computer. But none of the executables seem to work. But launching it from Ubuntu Software does work. Strange...

Comment: @Adriaan OK, it will definitely be different if you've installed it as a snap vs. a .deb.  I've updated my answer to factor that in.

Comment: The command `snap run freecad.FreeCAD` starts FreeCAD. The `freecad.FreeCAD` is located in the directory `/snap/bin`. Thanks for the hint.